# Apache and large file uploading

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I would like to upload quite large files on my site ~100Mb. My question is - is true that at some moment Apache is storing whole file in memory?

I'm using php and memory_limit is set to 128Mb, but I still get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 95223000 bytes)
```

UPD

For file uploading I use [Valums file uplaoder](https://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader). Here is a js code of uploader initialization:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    element: document.getElementById('file_upload_1'),
    action: '/handle/uploadfile',
    debug: true,
    uploadButtonText: "",
    sizeLimit: 256 * 1024 * 1024,
    onSubmit: function(id, fileName){
         ...
    },
    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
     ...    
});
```

The thing is that php action 'handle/uploadfile' is not even called. Error occurred when Apache processes POST request with file before pass it to php script.

Comment: Could you show some code? It is hard to make a correction without it. Also, what line are you getting that error? I'm assuming as you are moving the file, but impossible to tell.

Comment: Thanks for response. I updated post, but the thing is that error occurred during Apache processing of POST request, so problem is not in my PHP script.

Comment: And yet the error comes from php...odd.